# Turn on a Network Adapter over another One

Tags: windows-10, networking, internet

In my system I have two network adapters, one is for the Internet and the other one is for the local network.

When I need to use the internet, I will disable the local network adapter and enable the internet adapter and vice versa. It is an annoying process and it takes about a minute to switch from local to internet.

So instead of disabling the internet adapter, I will enable it forever, and whenever I need local, I will enable the local so it wraps the internet and will enable the local. Whenever I need the internet I just disable the local and the internet (which is always enabled) will affect as soon as possible.

I have written a batch script doing this: (it will turn on the local adapter (named `Unternet`) if it is disabled and vice versa)

```
@echo off
Set "_localState="
Set _localState=YES
netsh interface show interface "Unternet" | find "Administrative state" | find "Enabled">nul || Set _localState=NO
if %_localState%==NO (
netsh interface set interface "Unternet" enable
) ELSE (
netsh interface set interface "Unternet" disable
)
```

it works well on my system, but when I try it on another system, it will not. Where is the problem? and How can I turn on/off the local network over the internet network is such a fast way?

Comment: What is the reason for this setup? Why do you need to disable the local network adapter at all?

Comment: @StarCat if the local network enables over the internet, then only local will work and internet not! so I should disable the local to use the internet again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the network adapter's priority. I set the local adapter's priority higher than the internet adapter's priority and now everything works well.

Here is more information:
https://www.windowscentral.com/how-change-priority-order-network-adapters-windows-10

Answer (score 2):

To give the definitive answer for the reason, the information given in the question is not enough. But here are some major hooks that might trigger your problem.

##### Some possible problems

###### Privileges

To execute changes like `netsh interface SET ...` you have to execute the command with administrative privileges.

Preferably you create a `shortcut.lnk` to the batch and configure the shortcut to execute the `cmd.exe` with administrative privileges.

###### The name of the interface (Line 4)

Take into account that (at the other system) an interface named "Unternet" might not exist. To catch the problem insert this code between line 3 and 4:

```python
netsh interface show interface "Unternet">nul
if ERRORLEVEL 1 (
   echo "ERR: Problem with interface Unternet."
) else ( ...
```

Your check for the strings `Administrative state` and `Enabled` is subject to the language settings of the system. I.e. here the output of a German system:

```python
netsh interface show interface "Unternet"

Unternet
   Typ:                  Dediziert
   Verwaltungsstatus:    Aktiviert
   Verbindungsstatus:    Verbunden
```

*=> In case of a different system language `_localState=NO` is **always** the resulting state.*

To get independent of the language settings testing the `ERRORLEVEL` would be helpful. But `netsh` will not help in this case, as its errorlevel only states that `netsh` execution succeeded.

I suggest to use `ipconfig.exe` :

By the inserted check above line 4 we know at line 4 that a device "Unternet" exists (not regarding its state).
Checking the device via `ipconfig` the device will only show up when active (in contrast to `netsh`'s output).
So we can see at the ERRORLEVEL of `find` if the device is ENABLED or DISABLED when filtering by the device name:

```
ipconfig /allcompartments | find /I "Unternet">nul
if ERRORLEVEL 1 ( ...
```

Note that the check `if ERRORLEVEL 1 ...` turns TRUE for *all values equal 1 or higher*.

---

##### Solution

The final script (slightly optimized) could be like this:
(start it with Admin privileges)

```python
@echo off
::   Configure the net device name of the local LAN:
set localNetDev=Unternet

::   Check the existence of the net device:
netsh interface show interface "%localNetDev%">nul
if ERRORLEVEL 1 (
    echo "ERR: Problem with interface '%localNetDev%'."
) else (
    ipconfig /allcompartments | find /I "%localNetDev%">nul
    if ERRORLEVEL 1 (
        ::   %localNetDev%  is DISABLED – Switch it on:
        netsh interface set interface "%localNetDev%" enable
    ) else (
        ::   %localNetDev%  is ENABLED – Switch it OFF:
        netsh interface set interface "%localNetDev%" disable
    )
)

::   View result:
echo New state:
netsh interface show interface "%localNetDev%"
```

Comment: My answer does not regard the effectiveness of the access results as in the question the functionality is explaned as working. The open question is only the point that the script sometimes fails.